# C parentheses around comparison in operand

Tags: c

When compile a program in C, have an error:

```
error: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of '!=' [-Werror=parentheses]
```

The line generated this error is the line of while in this code:

```
void addProductToStock(tStock *stock, tProduct product) {
    int i;
    bool found;

    i = 1;
    found = false;

    while (i <= (*stock).numProd != found) {
        if ((*stock).products[i].productCode != product.productCode) {
            i++;
        }
        else {
            found = true;
        }

    }

    (*stock).products[i].availableUnits = (*stock).products[i].availableUnits - product.unitsRequested;
    (*stock).products[i].unitsRequested = (*stock).products[i].unitsRequested + product.unitsRequested;
}
```

How I can fix the error? Appreciate the help with an explanation.

Comment: What is this supposed to even mean: `while (i <= (*stock).numProd != found) {`

Comment: `while (i <= (*stock).numProd != found)` has confused the while loop. maybe `while (i <= (*stock).numProd && !found)`

Comment: What is going on the while clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, you probably want to change

```
while (i <= (*stock).numProd != found)
```

to

```
while (i <= (*stock).numProd && !found)
```

You're checking you're not exceeding the array bounds *and* that the product hasn't been found yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (i <= (*stock).numProd != found) {
```

If you’re trying to loop while `i <= (*stock).numProd` and `found` isn’t true, you’d want `&&` and `!`, not `!=`.

```
while (i <= (*stock).numProd && !found) {
```

`break`ing after you’ve found a match would work even better.

```
while (i <= stock->numProd) {
    if (stock->products[i].productCode != product.productCode) {
        i++;
    } else {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Also, are you sure your array goes from `1` to `numProd`? Usually it’d be `0` to `numProd - 1`.

Finally, `for` loops do this.

```
for (i = 1; i <= stock->numProd; i++) {
    if (stock->products[i].productCode == product.productCode) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If my ability to read incorrect code serves me well, you want to change this line:

`while (i <= (*stock).numProd != found) {`

to

`while (i <= (*stock).numProd && !found) {`